# If $g\in G$ and ${\rm ord}(g)=7$ and $h\in G$ s.t. ${\rm ord}(h)=11$ then find the minimun value of $|G|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a group.
If $g\in G$ and ${\rm ord}(g)=7$ and $h\in G$ such that ${\rm ord}(h)=11$ then find the minimun value of $|G|$

**My attempt**

As $g\in G$ then by Lagrange theorem we have that ${\rm ord}(g) = 7$ divide $|G|$

The same applies to: $h\in G$ then ${\rm ord}(h)=11$ divide $|G|$

From this we can conclude that the minimun $|G|$ is $77$.

Is correct this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost. You can deduce from that that the minimum is *at least* $77$. If you want to confirm that it actually *is* $77$, then the simplest option consists in provide an example. And $\Bbb Z_{77}$ will do, since $|\Bbb Z_{77}|=77$ and $\Bbb Z_{77}$ has elements with order $7$ and $11$.

Comment: While this will be an isomorphic example, I think it is easier to take $\mathbb Z_7 \times \mathbb Z_{11}$.  Then $(1,0)$ is of order 7 and $(0,1)$ is of order $11$.  Again, it is an isomorphic example, but a different perspective which makes it more obvious/natural to me.